# Why the output of this function is 0 when n=100?

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion, integer

```
int f(int n)
{
    static int r=0;
    if(n<=0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(n>3)
    {
        r=n;
        return f(n-2)*2;
    }
    return f(n-1)+r;
}
```

When n=10 or n=50 I am getting a positive integer as output but when n is in the range 70 to 100 I am getting 0 as output. According to my knowledge if ***out of range of int*** occurs then it will follow a circular order and start again from 0 but in this case, **it is always getting 0 as an output**. Can you please explain the reason?

Comment: Use a debugger? And `C` and `C++` are different languages. Tag only one for which you want the answer.

Comment: If out of range of int occurs then you are in big trouble because signed integer overflow is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Even though signed int overflow is ub, 0 being the result here is a good assumption to make: The prime factorization of the result assuming `int` can hold arbitraty numbers contains 2 with a power greater than 45. Every multiplication by 2 is equivalent to inserting a 0 as least significant bit so when in the end you only consider the least significant 32 bit, they are all 0s...

Comment: If `n` is 59, the result is also 0. This is the smallest value of `n` that gives 0, for some positive `n`.

Comment: debugging: https://ideone.com/xXp4t8

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this line.

```
f(n-2)*2;
```

Note that `int`s are stored in binary. This is equivalent to getting the value of `f(n-2)`, and shifting all of its bits one space to the left. (If `f(n-2)` were to be unsigned, the expression would be equivalent to `f(n-2)<<1)`.

For sufficiently large values of `n`, if you keep on shifting bits to the left, you'll end up with `0` when the `int` eventually overflows.

It seems, in your case, that value of `n` is `59`, although due to your program logic, `n = 60, 62, 64` all give non-zero results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Your problem is because of being Out Of Rane.
It shows always zero because the LSB part of that is zero. As I calculated the return value, that is 9*2^49, which is 5,066,549,580,791,808 decimal and if you convert it to hexadecimal form, It would be 0x12000000000000. This is totally out of range of an `int` variable.
So It is better to use `int64_t` from `stdint.h` to use that. 
Note that for `printf` you have to split it to two 32bit number. 
The code below may be help you.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t f(int64_t n)
{
    static int64_t r=0;
    if(n<=0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(n>3)
    {
        r=n;
        return f(n-2)*2;
    }
    return f(n-1)+r;
}

int main()
{
    int64_t retf = f(100);
    printf("MSB ret: 0x%x\n", (int)(retf >> 32));
    printf("LSB ret: 0x%x\n", (int)retf);
    return 0;
}
```